# Jenkins Push Button Deployment

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a QA environment Jenkins Job and I am looking to pass specific build number to deploy when I hit 'Push button' of Jenkins. Is there any plugin which could do this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the box 'This project is parameterized' and add a string parameter for the build number. Then use the variable as ${VAR_NAME} in the job.

You can set a useful default value, I typically use 'lastSuccessfulBuild'.

Comment: Is there any way we could use different Jenkins Job 'lastSuccessfulBuild' artifact and use that artifact for deployment in current jenkins job? Thanks.